# MySQL count occurrences greater than 2

Tags: mysql

I have the following table structure

```
+  id  +  word  +
+------+--------+
```

The table gets filled with the words in lower cas of a given text, so the text

Hello bye hello

would result in

```
+  id  +  word  +
+------+--------+
+   1  + hello  +
+------+--------+
+   2  + bye    +
+------+--------+
+   3  + hello  +
+------+--------+
```

I want to make a SELECT query that will return the number of words that get repeated at least two times in the table (like hello)

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM words WHERE (SELECT COUNT(words.word))>1
```

which of course is so wrong and super overloading when table is big. Any idea on how to achieve such purpose? In the given example inhere-above, I would expect 1

Comment: Anyone else seeing the underscores like a "sagging" rope bridge?

Answer (score 303, accepted):

To get a list of the words that appear more than once together with how often they occur, use a combination of GROUP BY and HAVING:

```
SELECT word, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM words
GROUP BY word
HAVING cnt > 1
```

To find the number of words in the above result set, use that as a subquery and count the rows in an outer query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT NULL
    FROM words
    GROUP BY word
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) T1
```

Comment: Just an addon, you can use the alias as well in "having". Like
SELECT words, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM words
GROUP BY word
HAVING cnt > 1

Comment: The first example works well only grouping Data

Comment: First one worked, Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

```
SELECT count(word) as count 
FROM words 
GROUP BY word
HAVING count >= 2;
```

Comment: CodeIgniter also supports having, so this was perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

`SELECT word, COUNT(*) FROM words GROUP by word HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Answer (score 3):

The HAVING option can be used for this purpose and query should be

```
SELECT word, COUNT(*) FROM words 
GROUP BY word
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```